# Integrating Sylius packages into Laravel project

Tags: symfony, laravel, doctrine-orm, sylius

I am attempting to use some Sylius packages in a Laravel project I'm building. I have added the packages to my project with composer, and the classes seem to be autoloading fine.

Now I want to do something with it. Let's take a simple example from the Sylius docs:

```
public function myAction()
{
    $repository = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.address');
    $manager = $this->container->get('sylius.manager.address'); // Alias to the appropriate doctrine manager service.

    $address = $repository->createNew();

    $address
        ->setFirstname('John')
        ->setLastname('Doe')
    ;

    $manager->persist($address);
    $manager->flush(); // Save changes in database.
}
```

I would like to recreate something like this in Laravel. I've created a simple test route to attempt this, but my problems are:

- How do I get a repository?
- How do I get a Doctrine manager service?

So I also included the laravel-doctrine package in an attempt to get a manager service, and then I just manually created a Product object, so that now I have:

```
Route::get('test', function() {
  $entityManager = new Doctrine;

  $product = new \Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product;
  $product->setName('Bla');

  Doctrine::persist($product);
  Doctrine::flush();

  dd($product);
});
```

This creates an error: `Class "Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product" sub class of "Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Product" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`

I'm not sure where to go next. My understanding of Doctrine is limited, but my understanding was that the Sylius components are decoupled from Symfony, and that I could just use them. But it seems that the annotations (or xml definitions) don't exist for Doctrine to operate properly.

Any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Laravel and symfony are completely different. You can't use a symfony bundle in a laravel project. If you want to use Sylius, you have to use the Symfony framework. If you want to use laravel, you have to search for another ecommerce platform.

Comment: Generally I agree with you. Bute note that he's willing to use the Sylius **Components, not the Bundles**. Sylius components can be *installed and used in any PHP application* according to the Sylius doc http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/components_and_bundles/components/general/index.html